# App Crashing when entering the foreground

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5

I recently added MDProgressHUD to my app and followed the instructions in the ReadMe document which advises me to setup the HUD on the main queue and then execute other tasks on a new thread which is how I have implemented it. It all works fine on the initial start up of the app, but if you select the home button on the phone so that the app is placed into the background and then select the app's icon to restore it to the foreground the app is crashing.

I have implemented the code as follows. When the user selects the OK button, the app will authenticate their login ID and password by calling a web service (NSURLConnection), i.e. authenticateUser.

```
- (IBAction)Ok:(id)sender {

    [self.txtPassword resignFirstResponder];

    [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.01 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
       [self authenticateUser];
       [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });

}

- (void)authenticateUser {

   self.loginEmailAddress = self.txtEmailAddress.text;
   self.loginPassword = self.txtPassword.text;

   if ([self.loginEmailAddress isEqualToString:@""] || [self.loginPassword isEqualToString:@""]) {
    self.lblErrMsg.text = @"Invalid login details. Please try again.";
    self.lblErrMsg.hidden = NO;
    [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    return;
}


    NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"org_id=%@&login_id=%@&pword=%@", signedUpOrgId, self.loginEmailAddress, self.loginPassword];
    NSString *myEncodedRequestString = [myRequestString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSData *myRequestData = [myEncodedRequestString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceURL
                                                      cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                    timeoutInterval:60.0];


    [theRequest setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: myRequestData];

    NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (theConnection) {
        receivedData = [NSMutableData data];

    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry! Can't connect." message:@"Sorry, but there seems to be a problem connecting to the internet at the moment. Please try again or wait until you have better reception for a data connection." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Logs:

```
2012-07-17 23:40:33.699 AppName[6155:707] -[ContactListViewController authenticateUser]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2616e0
2012-07-17 23:40:33.704 AppName[6155:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ContactListViewController authenticateUser]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2616e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3146588f 0x377a3259 0x31468a9b 0x31467915 0x313c2650 0x31d78933 0x31439a33 0x31439699 0x3143826f 0x313bb4a5 0x313bb36d 0x33435439 0x30b1ecd5 0xe13c7 0xe136c)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

I can't figure out why the app crashes the second time. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the code you posted for `authenticateUser` actually in a class called `ContactListViewController`?  (If it is, try running with Instruments, using the setting that checks for zombies.)

Comment: Have you declared your method in your `.h` file? Because it seems that you're trying to call the method before its implementation. One quick way to test it is to move the method above `- (IBAction)Ok:(id)sender`

Comment: @Alladinian this is an Objective-C runtime error, where .h files are meaningless (you don't need to declare a method anywhere for the runtime to attempt to find it and run it, and the runtime does not use header info to do that lookup (only the compiler does).

Comment: @ctrahey Fair enough. Thanx mate.

Answer (score 0):

When referencing `self` in a block, it is advisable to do it indirectly through a "weak" variable (else you may never get deallocated properly).

__weak ContactListViewController *weakself = self;
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
   [weakself authenticateUser];
   [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:weakself.view animated:YES];
});

This is because a reference to you is bound to that block; and it has an important implication: are you *sure* that you are hanging around long enough for this block to have a good reference to you? You may need to think that through and make sure that the object which is `self` when that gets called "belongs" to someone else for long enough to still be a valid instance with this block executes.